# Private nexus repository failed to download *.jar from central repository

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

I set up a private nexus repository. When I used a library that the private repository don't contain it, it should try to download it from central repository. But the fact is, it just downloaded a *.pom file for me. But when I commented the mirror like below

```
<mirrors>
<mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>local private nexus</name>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
</mirrors>
```

it then worked! Is there anyone can explain it for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall? Perhaps Nexus needs to have a HTTP proxy configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's something wrong with your Nexus configuration.

When the mirror is commented out, Maven goes to central directly w/o using Nexus, so it works.

I think it's worthing checking your Nexus log for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right I got something wrong in the configuration.